# Encountered exception javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method check

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I have been getting a series of error messages when trying to deploy a web application to an instance of tomcat 7.0.35 server installed on my computer.  The application is developed in jsp using eclipse.

The first error message I received was:

```
FAIL - Encountered exception javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method check
```

The above error message came after I tried to deploy the application in the tomcat manager application.

I have an xml file named myapp.xml placed in the root folder of the application in the workspace, and its contents are:

```
<Context path="/myapp" docBase="d:\path\to\myapp"/>
```

I tried to resolve this error message a number of different ways, with no effect.  After some time, an error message started to appear as well.

Finally, every few seconds, the console is refreshing with a large batch of new error messages from its continued retries, and those error messages include the following:

```
Feb 8, 2013 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor d:\mypath\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\conf\Catalina\localhost\myapp.xml
Feb 8, 2013 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor d:\mypath\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\conf\Catalina\localhost\myapp.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\mypath\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\conf\Catalina\localhost\myapp.xml (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:608)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Feb 8, 2013 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptors
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of context descriptors to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1449)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.addWatchedResources(HostConfig.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:706)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

It seems to be throwing a null pointer error when tomcat looks for myapp.xml within a tomcat folder.  But it does not seem to be seeing that myapp.xml is located in my eclipse workspace, at the d:\path\to\myapp url that I gave in the tomcat manager application, as shown above.  And it seems like the problem is getting worse as I keep trying new things.

Can anyone show me how to fix all this so that I can deploy my application on tomcat?  I have deployed other application on this server using similar methods without problems before this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this error by uninstalling and then re-installing both eclipse and tomcat.